# Reflection at time $s$ of a brownian motion

Tags: probability, solution-verification, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

I am self-learning introductory stochastic calculus from *A first course in stochastic Calculus*, by Louis Pierre Arguin. I would like to ask, if the below proof attempt is technically correct and rigorous.

> **Proposition**(*Reflection at time $s$*). Let $(B_t,t\geq 0)$ be a standard Brownian motion. The process $(-B_{t},t\geq0)$ is a Brownian
> motion. More generally, for any $s\geq0$, the process $(\tilde{B}(t),t\geq0)$
> defined by:

> \begin{align}
> \tilde{B}(t) & =\begin{cases}
> B_{t} & \text{if }t\leq s\\
> B_{s}-(B_{t}-B_{s}) & \text{if }t>s
> \end{cases}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

is a Brownian motion.

***My Proof Attempt.***

---

(a) Consider the process $\tilde{B}(t)=(-B_{t},t\geq0)$.

(1) $\tilde{B}(0)=0$.

(2) If $X$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance
$t-s$, $-X$ is also Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $t-s$.
Thus, $\tilde{B}(t)-\tilde{B}(s)=-(B(t)-B(s))$ is also Gaussian with
mean $0$ and variance $(t-s)$. Hence condition (2) is satisfied.

(3) Assume that $0\leq t_{0}\leq t_{1}\leq\ldots\leq t_{n}$. Then,
the random variables $-(B(t_{k})-B(t_{k-1}))$ are independent for
$k=1,2,3,\ldots,n$. Hence, condition (3) is satisfied.

Consequently, $(-B(t),t\geq0)$ is a Brownian Motion.

---

(b) Fix an $s\geq0$. Consider the process $\tilde{B}(t)$ as defined in (1).

(1) Let $t=0$. Then, $t\leq s$. $\tilde{B}(t)=\tilde{B}(0)=B(0)=0$.

(2) Let $t_{1}<t_{2}\leq s$. Then, $\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1})=B(t_{2})-B(t_{1})$.
This is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $t_{2}-t_{1}$.

Let $t_{1}<s<t_{2}$. Then, $\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1})=B(s)-(B(t_{2})-B(s))-B(t_{1})=(B(s)-B(t_{1}))-(B(t_{2})-B(s))$.
Since, $B(s)-B(t_{1})$ and $B(t_{2})-B(s)$ are independent Gaussian
random variables, any linear combination of these is Gaussian. Moreover,
its mean is zero. The variance is given by:

\begin{align*}
Var[\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1})] & =Var[B(s)-B(t_{1})]+Var[B(t_{2})-B(s)]\\
 & =(s-t_{1})+(t_{2}-s)\\
 & =t_{2}-t_{1}
\end{align*}

Let $s<t_{1}<t_{2}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1}) & =B_{s}-(B_{t_{2}}-B_{s})-(B_{s}-(B_{t_{1}}-B_{s}))\\
 & =-(B_{t_{2}}-B_{t_{1}})
\end{align*}

Hence, $\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1})$ is again a Gaussian random
variable with mean $0$ and variance $t_{2}-t_{1}$. Hence, condition
(3) is satisfied.

(3) Assume that $0\leq t_{1}\leq\ldots\leq t_{k-1}\leq s\leq t_{k}\leq\ldots\leq t_{n}$.

From the above discussion, the increments $\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1})$,
$\ldots$, $\tilde{B}(s)-\tilde{B}(t_{k-1})$, $\tilde{B}(t_{k})-\tilde{B}(s)$,
$\ldots$, $\tilde{B}(t_{n})-\tilde{B}(t_{n-1})$ are independent
increments. The increment $\tilde{B}(t_{k})-\tilde{B}(t_{k-1})$ only
depends on the random variables $\tilde{B}(s)-\tilde{B}(t_{k-1})$
and $\tilde{B}(t_{k})-\tilde{B}(s)$. Thus, $\tilde{B}(t_{2})-\tilde{B}(t_{1})$,
$\ldots$, $\tilde{B}(t_{k})-\tilde{B}(t_{k-1})$, $\ldots$, $\tilde{B}(t_{n})-\tilde{B}(t_{n-1})$

are independent.

Comment: Your proofs look correct to me, though you should really mention something about the continuity of sample paths in both cases